# Issue pluging-in an effect for state management

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

Managing state is giving errors in my Angular 8.0 app using NgRx 8.2.

```
export interface AppState {
  loggedIn: boolean;
  userInfo: IPrincipal;
}

export interface State {
  state: AppState;
}

export interface IPrincipal {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

I have written a simple Login service that returns the required information

Action has been defined like

```
export const login = createAction('[Login Initiatied] Login',
  props<{ principal: IPrincipal }>()
);

export const loginSuccess = createAction('[Login Success] Login',
  props<{ userProfile: IUserProfile }>()
);

export const loginFailure = createAction('[Login Failure] Login',
  props<{ message: any }>()
);
```

Userprofile is just another interface with some more details

```
export interface IUserProfile {
  user: IPrincipal;
  first: string;
  last: string;
}
```

When I am trying to plugin an effect

```
import * as AppActions from './actions/login.action';

login$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AppActions.login),
    map( action => action.principal),
    exhaustMap( (principal: IPrincipal) =>
      this.loginService.loginUser(principal.email, principal.password).pipe(
        map(userProfile => of( AppActions.loginSuccess({ userProfile }))),
        catchError(message => of( AppActions.loginFailure({ message })))
      )
    )
  )
  );
```

I tried several things but in my effects for the `login$` I am getting these errors

```
ERROR in src/app/app.effects.ts(32,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action> | ((...args: any[]) => Observable<Action>)'.
      Type 'Observable<{} | Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
        Type '{} | Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">>' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
          Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Action'.


    ERROR in src/app/app.effects.ts(32,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action> | ((...args: any[]) => Observable<Action>)'.
      Type 'Observable<Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
        Type 'Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
          Property 'type' is missing in type 'Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">>' but required in type 'Action'.


    ERROR in src/app/app.effects.ts(32,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action> | ((...args: any[]) => Observable<Action>)'.
      Type 'Observable<Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
        Type 'Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
          Property 'type' is missing in type 'Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">>' but required in type 'Action'.


    ERROR in src/app/app.effects.ts(32,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action> | ((...args: any[]) => Observable<Action>)'.
      Type 'Observable<Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Action>'.
        Type 'Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">> | ({ message: any; } & TypedAction<"[Login Failure] Login">)' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
          Property 'type' is missing in type 'Observable<{ userProfile: IUserProfile; } & TypedAction<"[Login Success] Login">>' but required in type 'Action'.
```

It is somethind obvious I am missing, but just cant get my head around to see what I have missed.

```
map(userProfile => of( AppActions.loginSuccess({ userProfile })))
```

It is suppose to return an Observable of Action but it is complaining of not.

I was able to create successfully, by using the earlier version implementation by exporting a class of Action and utilizing that in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an action from your effect so this line of code

```
map(userProfile => of( AppActions.loginSuccess({ userProfile })))
```

You can change to

```
map(userProfile => new AppActions.loginSuccess({ userProfile }))
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to do the following and it solved.  ```map((userProfile) => AppActions.loginSuccess({userProfile}))```

Comment: Can't believe I just kept looking at it and the exception still ignoring the ```of()```